# Does installing, deleting and reinstalling an app make your phone slower?

Tags: installation, uninstallation, performance

I recently bought my oneplus 7 pro and I was wondering if installing a certain app, deleting it, and reinstalling it again makes my phone slower. I was forced to do this to a certain application today.

Comment: Reinstalling an app is no different than installing a new app. App performance is a function of the device's hardware (ageing affects performance because of new apps developed for better hardware in mind) and code optimization AFAIK. None of this seems to be the case with your app and the device so it should not affect the performance.

Comment: The only possible way I see to make your phone slower by re-installing an app would be that the flash memory degrades a very tiny bit - but that is pure theory. In reality before that effect would be recognizable to you, you would have to re-install an 100MB app a thousand times every day for may be a year or more.